# cross compiling Java JNI libraries for Windows / RPi from OS X / Linux

Tags: gcc, fortran, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi

I have access to a 64 bit OS X environment, but I'd like to dramatically reduce the process for releasing native library builds for `x86` / `x86_64` / `armv6` Linux and 32 / 64 bit Windows.

**How can I cross compile JNI code from OS X (and failing that, from 64 bit Ubuntu Linux)?** Which compilers must I install (I'm using `macports`) and from where can I install the foreign JDK environments that I must include and link against? What special compiler / linker flags are needed?

I'm using the [maven-native-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-native/native-maven-plugin/) so I can easily change the compiler, linker and `JDK_HOME` for every target. I have one module (i.e. `pom.xml`) per target platform.

The project, for those interested in details, is [netlib-java/native_ref](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java/tree/master/native_ref).

Comment: Why not Linux/WIN32/whatever as VMs on your OS X machine, enable some shared directories, and then do everything "native" on a single machine from a single shared code base ?

Comment: That's how I get access to Linux from OS X. I don't have spare licenses to do the same for Windows. It is exhausting and not even an option for ARM. A single maven build command would dramatically simplify my builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out that various Linux cross-compilers come with `macports` in the form of

- `arm-elf-gcc`
- `i386-elf-gcc`
- `x86_64-elf-gcc`
- `i386-mingw32-gcc`

with 64 bit Windows cross-compile [on its way](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/40174).

Unfortunately, for my purposes I also need a Fortran compiler, so I'm asking for more help on that now on the [macports mailing lists](https://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-users/2013-August/033271.html)

**EDIT**: the current state of fortran cross-compilers (and mingw in general) on OS X is woeful. Best advice at the moment is to run a Linux box in VirtualBox and cross-compile all the targets from there. Two builds, not optimal, but better than all native.

Comment: I believe now there is a commonly used MinGW for Win64, on Ubuntu, the package is `gcc-mingw-w64`.